# React Component - render return throwing syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

Still fairly new to React, having a strange syntax issue.  I'm creating a React Component, I believe I've got the correct opening/closing { & }'s, but I guess I must be missing something based off the error it's throwing? Here's my code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TreeList, SearchPanel, Scrolling, Lookup } from 'devextreme-react/tree-list';
import 'devextreme-react/text-area';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import WireGrid from '../WireGrid.js'

const expandedRowKeys = [1];
// const allowedPageSizes = [5, 10, 15, 20];
class WireTree extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    jsonData: null
  }
this.onFocusedRowChanged = this.onFocusedRowChanged.bind(this)
}

async componentDidMount() {
const url = "http://localhost:4741/wiretree";
const response = await fetch(url);
const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        'jsonData' : data.recordset
    })
}

onFocusedRowChanged(e) {
var rowData = e.row && e.row.data,
cellValue
if(rowData) {
  cellValue = e.component.cellValue(e.row.rowIndex, 'Filter');
  module.export = cellValue
  if (!cellValue) {
    return null;
  } else {
    console.log('cellValue: ', cellValue)
    // <WireGrid />
  }
}} 
}

render() {
  return (
    <TreeList
      id="wireTree"
      dataSource={this.state.jsonData}
      dataStructure="plain"
      rootValue=""
      defaultExpandedRowKeys={expandedRowKeys}
      columnAutoWidth={true}
      keyExpr="categoryID"
      parentIdExpr="ParentID"
      wordWrapEnabled={true}
      focusedRowEnabled={true}
      virtualModeEnabled={true}
      onFocusedRowChanged={this.onFocusedRowChanged}
    >
      <SearchPanel visible={true} />
      <Scrolling mode="standard" />
      <Lookup
        dataSource={this.state.jsonData}
        valueExpr="ID"
        displayExpr="Search" />
    </TreeList>
  );
}

export default WireTree;
```

Here's the error it shows in the console, it's pointing to the 'render() {' line:

```
 ';' expected. ts(1005) [42, 10]
```

Doesn't ts = TypeScript? Any thoughts?

Comment: You have a `}` too much right before the render function.

Comment: use a good editor, so that it'll alert you on the exact point where the error is detected.

Comment: @Taxel Oh interesting - I thought you were supposed to call the render/return outside of the Component?

Answer (score 0):

Find the correct formatted code below

render is placed outside the component, instead of closing component } before render remove it and place after the render as below

```
import React from 'react';
import { TreeList, SearchPanel, Scrolling, Lookup } from 'devextreme-react/tree-list';
import 'devextreme-react/text-area';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

const expandedRowKeys = [1];
class WireTree extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
jsonData: null
}
this.onFocusedRowChanged = this.onFocusedRowChanged.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch('http://localhost:4741/wiretree')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({ jsonData: res });
    });
    }

 onFocusedRowChanged(e) {
 var rowData = e.row && e.row.data,cellValue
 if(rowData) {
 cellValue = e.component.cellValue(e.row.rowIndex, 'Filter');
 module.export = cellValue
 if (!cellValue) {
 return null;
  } else {
  console.log('cellValue: ', cellValue)
  }
 }} 

 render() {
 return (
 <TreeList
 id="wireTree"
 dataSource={this.state.jsonData}
 dataStructure="plain"
 rootValue=""
 defaultExpandedRowKeys={expandedRowKeys}
 columnAutoWidth={true}
 keyExpr="categoryID"
 parentIdExpr="ParentID"
 wordWrapEnabled={true}
 focusedRowEnabled={true}
 virtualModeEnabled={true}
 onFocusedRowChanged={this.onFocusedRowChanged}>

<SearchPanel visible={true} />
<Scrolling mode="standard" />
<Lookup
dataSource={this.state.jsonData}
valueExpr="ID"
displayExpr="Search" />

</TreeList>
);
}
}
export default WireTree;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, even copy/pasting directly your code over mine still throws an error: ```<TreeList
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'``` Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Have edited, can you try this code and let me know if you are facing any syntax error

Comment: Just tried it again with the updated code, unfortunately still getting the same error...  :( ```<TreeList
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ```

Answer (score 0):

Function `onFocusedRowChanged` has { too much at the end.
You also need to close your class with } just before your export at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! If I add a ```}``` before my export at the bottom, my linter (using VS Code) throws an error of: ```Declaration or statement expected.``` in the console.  Any ideas on how to work around that?

Comment: You're welcome. 
I have no idea just seeing the code like this. It could be many things. Maybe a mis imported component, an error on the way you're exporting the current component, a variable already used as global etc etc. But after checking I didn't find anything, sorry